# How to compare two Dia diagrams?

Tags: dia

Is there any utility or add-on to make it possible to compare two Dia diagrams? I have a diagram of a database schema in Dia, mercurial tells me that the .dia file has changed, but I don't know what has changed. It's probably a field added into a table, but I can't tell. If I ask  mercurial for the difference, I see two binary files and it means nothing.

I went looking for add-ons. There is a page, http://sourceforge.net/projects/dia-grams/ but it doesn't have anything that would help. Actually, it doesn't seem to have any files at all at all. Maybe Dia doesn't have any plug-ins or add-ons yet? Nothing for comparing diagrams anyway?

Answer (score -1):

Found a way, and feeling silly that I didn't think of it before...

I renamed the file that I wanted to check in, to schema_new.dia. Then I reverted the file in Mercurial, so that I had the previous schema.dia. In Dia, I exported the images to .svg files schema.svg and schema_new.svg. Double-clicking on one of them opened it with the "Eye of MATE" viewer -- other environments will have their own viewers. I was able to flick back and forth between the two images, so that I could see exactly what the differences were.

Not as convenient as a plugin, but it got the job done.

Comment: I removed "Solved" from your title. A question is 'solved', as far as Stack Overflow is concerned, if it has an accepted answer - this will be visible in the various lists of questions. And if this worked for you, you are allowed to mark your own answer as "accepted"!